# Show $ 5 + \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} ≥ (1+a)(1 +b)(1+c)$ when $abc =1$

Tags: inequality

Just an inequality that I couldn't solve:

For $a,b,c$ positive reals such that $abc = 1$, show

$$5 + \frac{a}{b} +  \frac{b}{c}  + \frac{c}{a} \ge (1 + a)(1 + b)(1 + c).$$

WhatI have done so far: I have shown this is equivalent, after some algebra, to $3+a^2c+b^2a + c^2b \ge ab+bc+ac + a + b + c$, and I have absolutely no idea where to go from there.

Comment: What happened to your linear terms in $a$, $b$, $c$?

Comment: I was wrong, which means I'm much further from a solution than I thought - thanks, and edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substitute $a = u/v, b = v/w, c = w/ u$ to get rid of the constraint $abc=1$, and you have the equivalent inequality
$$\sum_{cyc} u^3v^3 + 3u^2v^2w^2 \ge uvw \sum_{cyc} uv(u+v)$$

Now let $x = uv, y = vw, z = wu$ and we get in these new variables the inequality:
$$\sum_{cyc} x^3 + 3xyz \ge  \sum_{cyc} xy(x+y)$$

which is the familiar [Schur's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur's_inequality).